# A disabled module has a schema version of -1, how can I enable the module and then run DB updates using hook_update_N?

Tags: 7, updating

The problem is, it seems when I enable a disabled module, the module's schema version in the system table is automatically updated to the latest version supplied by hook_update_N.

So my current module with the schema version -1 is modified to 7106 when I enable the module, and no hook_update_N functions are run.

So when I come to the next step of running database updates, no hook_update_N functions are run because the module thinks it's already the correct version.

The only method I can see is to manually set the module version in hook_enable, however I'll then need to update the module code to remove the hook_enable to make sure it doesn't run if the module is ever re-enabled in the future, so obviously this approach is a bit dirty.

I'm hoping there's a better solution?

Answer (score 5):

Disabling a module should *not* set the schema_version to -1. -1 means [SCHEMA_UNINSTALLED](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.inc/constant/SCHEMA_UNINSTALLED/7). As the constant says, it means this module has never been installed.

A module that has not been installed before is not supposed to run updates. `hook_schema()` is supposed to contain the current state of a module's schema. So this behavior is correct, and you should not mess around with the schema version manually.

If disabling (not uninstalling) a module really does set the schema_version to -1, then that's where things go wrong. But Drupal core isn't doing this, see [module_disable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7).

Also, note that Drupal executes updates for all installed modules, no matter if they're enabled or not.

Comment: "hook_update_n executes for all modules whether they are enabled or disabled" - I have observed this as well.  Could someone validate this statement with a reference?

Comment: It's not a statement, it's a fact :) But if you don't want to believe my word, read the code: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21update.inc/function/update_get_update_list/7. That loads all modules and skips only those that are uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the module (drush pm-uninstall) and then enable it again.

Comment: The module is part of a feature, so we need to have hook_update_N run after the feature revert, rather than hook_install which I imagine would happen before feature revert?

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like the only way I can think of would be to manually set the schema_version to 0 for the disabled module, as this seems to prevent it from inheriting a more advanced version number.

Still feels a little dirty, but at least I can handle this with SQL used in a deployment script rather than rely on hooks that could run more than once.

Comment: There are many Drupal modules, and none of them does what you are describing.